# Implement Bayes Net

Tags: java, c, bayesian-networks

Is there any `c` or `java` example implementing `Bayesian Net`?

I want to solve some things but Do not where to start?.

Comment: There are some potentially useful links here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network#Software_resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using JavaBayes with great success for my master thesis final project. Check it out under http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~javabayes/
It has a great set of examples, very decent documentation, a graphical designer and very useful API.

I remember I did a little research regarding available Bayesian Networks implementations in Java and I was pleasantly surprised when I found this library. I can strongly recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

[Use Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/).  It not only implements Bayes Nets, but also a lot of other ML algorithms.